# devise - how to add validation to the users model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using rails 3 w devise. How can I add a validation to devise for a extra column in my user's table, column: first_name

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :first_name, :presence => true
end
```

Comment: turns out devise invitable skips validations

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but top of the google search. Needs new answer.

I ran into this same problem until I threw my new column/attribute into the 
attr_accessible chain. Then any validations I wrote were run properly.